# Django query filter many to many to many etc

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

Given these relationships:

> Publication -(n:m)- Article -(n:m)- Advert -(n:1)- Partner

how can I query to find all publications with adverts from a specific partner? e.g., something like:

```
result = Publication.objects.filter(articles.adverts.partner = partner)
```

Comment: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to a foreign key (or foreign key attr) in your query using `__`.

Example:

```
result = Publication.objects.filter(articles__adverts__partner = partner)
```

**TIP:** `__` <-- This is 2 underscores (`_ _`)

Let's supose your `Partner` model has a field called `username`, you could also do like:

```
result = Publication.objects.filter(articles__adverts__partner__username = 'username')
```

you can also do:

```
result = Publication.objects.filter(articles__adverts__partner__username__icontains = 'adm')
```

Comment: Happy to help ! You should check some other *filters* like: `icontains`, `lt`, `lte`, `gt`, `gte`... that you can use to filter dates, or check users that contains 3 chars in their username etc... Django is awesome for this stuff !